# one-to-many mapping // how to map an association of legacy tables (Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, database-design, orm

I've got two  legacy database tables, layouted in simplified manner like this:

```
MASTER                        SLAVE
ident                         ident
sName                         sName
sNumber                       sNumber
sDesc                         sValue
-----                         ------
Java Class 'ScenarioMaster'   Java Class 'ScenarioSlave'
```

Each row has a surrogate index via the `ident` column, but there is no relationship between `MASTER.key` and `SLAVE.key`. However, for the `MASTER` table, uniqueness of one sName/sNumber pair is true. This would therefore be a possible and meaningful composite key (I do know that those are evil).

In fact, there is a 1:n relationship meaning each `MASTER` row references *n* rows in the `SLAVE` table. Given the column description from above, possible population could be

```
MASTER                        SLAVE
100                           42
'labl'                        'labl'
1                             1
'some label'                  0.1
                              43
                             'labl'
                              1
                              0.2
```

Now, using hibernate, how could I reflect this relationship in my java classes? In `ScenarioMaster` I would declare a Set or List with public getters/setters like

```
private List<ScenarioSlave> slaves = new ArrayList<ScenarioSlave>();
```

The hibernate-mappings for `ScenarioMaster` could contain

```
<bag name="slaves" cascade="all">
    <key>
        <column name="sName" not-null="true"/>
        <column name="sNumber" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="ScenarioSlave"/>
</bag>
```

This, however, creates a strage update statement when updating an already persitant `ScenarioMaster` entity using `session.saveOrUpdate(scenarioMaster)`.

```
// create master scn and slave slv      
scn.addSlave(slv);  
session.saveOrUpdate(scn);

    Hibernate: 
        update
            SLAVE
        set
            sNumber=?,
            sName=?,
            sValue=?
        where
            sName=? 
            and sNumber=?
    Hibernate: 
        update
            SLAVE
        set
            sName=null,
            sNumber=null 
        where
            sName=? 
            and sNumber=?
```

What am I doing wrong? Where is that second update coming from? 
I guess it has something to do with sName/sNumber not being a key for `ScenarioSlave`. I can't quite figure out, why.

Note that the sName/sNumber parameters do point to valid values and that the `ScenarioMaster` instance I want to persist via `saveOrUpdate` actually has a non-null `ScenarioSlave` instance in the `slaves` List.

**EDIT**: Composite key is deferred to a separate class using this mapping

```
<composite-id name="keyId" class="ScenarioKeyId">
    <key-property name="name" access="field" column="sName"
        type="string" length="20"/>
    <key-property name="number" access="field" column="sNumber"
        type="long"/>
</composite-id>
```

I don't really want to create a table `NAMENUMBER_KEY` which maps *'labl', 1* to something like *'key_labl1'* which can then be used as `id` for hibernate. I suppose, this is what hibernate does (without making use of an actual table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate does not work well with composite keys, in my experience.  It's the one main problem with Hibernate as far as I've seen.  I've worked around it in the past by avoiding the use of "purely" composite keys; that is, I've given composite key tables a unique ID column which Hibernate can then work off of.

Comment: makes two of us (regarding the introducing of unique Id colum)

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one who uses / used that solution.  It's a little frustrating to have to do, from a DB design perspective, but it really fixes the problem good.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that approach? Do you ALTER TABLE your table when saying 'given composite key tables a unique ID column'? I'm afraid I can't do this, but I also doubt this is what you did.

Comment: Testing during initial development showed the problem with Hibernate and composite keys, so we changed the initial specification of the table to include a separate primary key column for that table.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit around (gotta love [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)) pretending, both tables did not have a composite ID.
Then I found out, that the `SET ... = null` statement most likely is being issued to invalidate members of the `slave` list.

```
create table MASTER(
   ident numeric(10) not null, -- key column
   name char(20) not null,
   number numeric(10) not null,
   descr char(64) not null
);

create table SLAVE(
   ident numeric(10) not null, -- key column
   name char(20) not null,
   number numeric(10)   ,      -- foreign key f. MASTER.ident
   value float not null
);
```

Here is my test code. I set the generator for the master class key as `assigned`.

```
        Master master = new Master();
        master.setIdent(Integer.valueOf(0));
        master.setName("name");
        master.setNumber(42);
        master.setDescr("name/42 descr");
        Slave slv = new Slave("name", 42, 0.001);
        master.addSlave(slv);
        theSession.beginTransaction();
        theSession.saveOrUpdate(master);
        theSession.getTransaction().commit();
```

Then, allowing `NULL` values in the `SLAVE.number` row, I get

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        SLAVE 
    set
        number=null 
    where
        number=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        SLAVE 
    set
        number=? 
    where
        ident=?
```

Now I only have to figure out how to actually delete stale rows in `SLAVE` rather then setting the foreign key column to `NULL`...